# Reading a particular Digit from a given number in shell

Tags: bash, shell, operating-system, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For example I have 6 digit number 234566, I have to read all the numbers digit by digit like

**output**

2

3

4

5

6

6

I tried this

```
read a #reads a six digit number 
j=1
n=1
while [ $n -le 6 ]
do
    for j in $a
    do
       echo $j
    done
    j=$((j+1))
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

but its giving the same number 6 times.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Your code looks really strange. Are you sure you tested it? I do not see how `while [ n -le 6 ]` would not cause an error. Anyway, `fold` is your friend here: `echo "$a" | fold -b1`.

Comment: Don't do arithmetic. Just split your string into individual characters.

Comment: `[ n -le 6 ]` is nonsense. `-le` is for arithmetic comparision. `n` is just the letter *n*, not a number.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet can you please elaborate , I am really new to this so have no clue..Thanks
And yes i messed up the code with variable names so i corrected it to what it was supposed to be

Comment: @shubhankargulati Just type `echo "234566" | fold -b1` to convince yourself that it does what you want. Then type `man fold` to learn about the `fold` utility.

Comment: Yep that works, I'll read about fold , thanks @RenaudPacalet